# Why is Gmail being delayed one week?

Tags: email, ios, gmail, iphone

It is just as weird as it sounds. I'm using the default mail app on my iPhone 6 with iOS 8.4.1. Ever since I have it, my mail has been showing up one week late. To be specific, I only get my mail at certain days of the week. At monday, there's no mail. At Tuesday, there's no mail. At wednesday, there's mail from Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday. Even if I fetch my mail manually, there still is nothing. Is there a solution to this? I've tried removing my Gmail account from my iPhone and putting it back, but it didn't work. I also couldn't find a flaw in the settings.